# Compile Time Incredibly Slow

Tags: xcode, swift3

My project consists of ~350 Swift files and ~40 cocoa pod dependencies.

As soon as the entire project was migrated to `Swift 3`, build times have been **INCREDIBLY** slow and took a little over 3 minutes to completely compile.
I've noticed that if I rebuild after not changing any files, it builds within a reasonable amount of time. However, if I add a new function, it takes the 3+ minutes.
Cocoapods does not seem to be causing the problem as it delays on `Compiling Swift source files` state.

I followed [this](http://irace.me/swift-profiling) to investigate:

1. Added the `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` flag to my `Other Swift Flags` in my target's build settings
2. Build the project
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. Copied this into terminal and ran `pbpaste | egrep '\.[0-9]ms' | sort -t "." -k 1 -n | tail -100`

However, I didn't see anything of concern. The file that took the longest to compile was only 250ms. The next closest was 100ms, even if all 350 files took 250ms to compile, that would only be a total of 73 seconds which is way off from the 3+ minute builds I am seeing.

#### What could be causing these long compile times?

It was never as slow before updating to `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3`.

Comment: I have also experienced slightly slower build times in Xcode 8, but not to this extent. Just wondering... what are the specs on your computer?

Comment: @TDM I am equipped with the following:  Late 2013 Macbook Pro, 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM, running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39514629/5175709) I wrote and ther answers to the question *may* help

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/41796332/2050181

Comment: This worked for me on Xcode 8.3 swift 3.1 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40497873/1890317 I went from over a minute build to 17 seconds

Comment: fwiw, at least on Xcode 8.3.2 I think you need to use `egrep '\.[0-9]+ms'` in step 5 (note the added `+` sign)

Answer (score 37):

### Update 1:

I created a new project without running the `Swift 3` conversion, imported my `Swift 3` files, but the build time remains the same.

### Update 2:

I've tried `SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES`, but as soon as you make changes to more than 1 file, the incremental build fails and it triggers a re-build which lasts for more than 4-5 minutes.

### Update 3:

I've now re-written my entire code base from `Swift 3` to `Swift 2.3`. It didn't make any difference, the problem lies with the `Xcode 8` compiler.

### Update 4:

I can confirm that unchecking these two [image: Dependency check]
will alleviate the pain for a while, the `Xcode 8` bug does seem to be tied to how it checks dependencies between files.

### Update 5:

I've converted my code base to `Swift 3` from `Swift 2.3` since `Xcode 8.2` beta requires it, the beta should include a fix for "Xcode will not rebuild an entire target when only small changes have occurred. (28892475)". Sad to say, they haven't fixed the bug and my compile times are exactly the same with `Xcode 8.2 Beta`.

### Original post:

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I still wanted to share some resources. I've been stuck in this misery for days, upgrading to `Swift 3` has been a complete disaster.

I'm using this to track slow files, even though just like you, that's not my problem. Something else in xcode is taking literally 4 minutes to complete:
https://github.com/irskep/swift_compile_times_parser
https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode

I've also made sure I don't have any `lazy vars` or `closures` that swift doesn't like. Don't use the `+ operator` when concatenating strings, etc.
[see this](https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-build-time-optimizations-part-2-37b0a7514cbe#.fgwiun207).

I'll update this answer if I find anything, it's just about impossible to be productive with `Swift 3` ATM.

Comment: How large is your project? And have you had any resolution since posting this answer?

Comment: How do you concatenate the Strings?

Comment: Where are the options of the Update 4?

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Xcode 8.1 My issue was with Dictionary which uses `Nil-Coalescing Operator`

this is my code when it takes 10 minutes to build:

```
    let params: [String:String] = [
        "email": email ?? self.email,
        "clave": password,
        "tipo_documento": documentType?.rawValue ?? self.typeDocument.rawValue,
        "documento": number ?? self.documentNumber,
        "nombre": name ?? self.name,
        "apellidos": lastName ?? self.lastName,
        "fecha_nacimiento": birth?.parse() ?? self.birthDate.parse(),
        "genero": genre?.rawValue ?? self.genre.rawValue,
        "telefono_movil": cel ?? self.cel,
        "direccion": address ?? self.address
    ]
```

I don't know why but it advertise me that the Dictionary take a long time to compile.

[image]

Then I change it to:

```
    var params: [String:String] = [:]
        params["email"] = email ?? self.email
        params["clave"] = password
        params["tipo_documento"] = documentType?.rawValue ?? self.typeDocument.rawValue
        params["documento"] = number ?? self.documentNumber
        params["nombre"] = name ?? self.name
        params["apellidos"] = lastName ?? self.lastName
        params["fecha_nacimiento"] = birth?.parse() ?? self.birthDate.parse()
        params["genero"] = genre?.rawValue ?? self.genre.rawValue
        params["telefono_movil"] = cel ?? self.cel
        params["direccion"] = address ?? self.address
```

Hope it could help some of you.

Comment: took me ages to figure this out, thanks! really weird and ridiculous. I cut the initial dictionary in half and then added the second one to the first one -> compile time fine. one big dictionary took forever. I actually never waited for it to finish.

Comment: Same problem with XCode 9.0 and 9.2

Answer (score 10):

**SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES**

Xcode version: **8.1 GM**

To add choose your target, then go to `Editor > Add Build Setting > Add User-Defined Setting`, and add the above.

My clean build time dropped from 35 mins (Ahem, excuse me) to 8 mins with a project file count of 800.

Note: *Tried this on Xcode 8.0 first, but didn't work.*

Comment: what does this do exactly, didn't seem to work for me or change anything.

Comment: This was recommended by Apple on their Release notes for Xcode 8.1. Not sure about the internals as I'm really new to iOS Development.

Answer (score 10):

Also `string concatenation` seems to be incredible slow in Swift3/XCode8:

```
item.text = item.text + " " + pickerText + " " + (attribute?.Prefix ?? "") + inputText + (attribute?.Suffix ?? "")
```

~ took 8-10 seconds to compile

```
item.text = "\(item.text) \(pickerText) \(attribute?.Prefix ?? "")\(inputText)\(attribute?.Suffix ?? "")"
```

~ took 1,6 seconds to compile

```
item.text = [item.text, " ", pickerText, " ", (attribute?.Prefix ?? ""), inputText, (attribute?.Suffix ?? "")].joined();
```

~ took 0,001 second to compile

Comment: From 185650.09ms to 95.45ms! Thank you very much. (Swift 3, XCode 8.3.3)

Comment: Testing the **execution** performance with Swift 4 I find that the `joined` array version is about 10x slower. than the 2 others How did you measure the compilation time ?

Answer (score 6):

I found a couple of coding styles that take a lot of time compiling in Swift (2.3, not tested on 3):

```
a += b
```

Should be

```
a = a + b
```

Also adding array together:

```
var a = [1,3,4]
var b = [5,6,7,8]
var c = [8,4,3,5]
var d = a + b + c
```

Should be

```
var a = [1,3,4]
var b = [5,6,7,8]
var c = [8,4,3,5]
var d : [Int] = []
d.appendContentsOf(a)
d.appendContentsOf(b)
d.appendContentsOf(c)
```

The last optimization took the compilation time for 1 method **from 9800ms to 5.5ms**...

Answer (score 2):

I migrated a Swift 2x project of 17 files to Swift 3 and had 28 warnings and 55 errors across all files. Compile time was 4-5 minutes.

Disabling

```
Find Implicit Dependancies
```

in scheme and

```
SWIFT_WHOLE_MODULE_OPTIMIZATION = YES
```

made only minor improvements.

As I eventually cleared the warnings and errors in each file, the compile time reduced and is now in the seconds. The IDE is back behaving as it should - detecting errors in near real time and compiling quickly.

Firstly, it looks like the compiler is recompiling (or at least cross checking) every file with any error or warning - even if you haven't edited that file since the last compile.

Secondly, if there are too many dependant errors/warnings across files, the compiler bottlenecks and slows right down.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face slow compilation issue, closly looks the the third party SDKs you included in your app and also try to find your coding techniques.

I face this issue twice in my app and I felt like harrassed by Swift 3 . Both the times reasons were different.

First time I found that I added a library in my app named [AASignatureView](https://github.com/EngrAhsanAli/AASignatureView). Since this lib was added, my compilation time increased like hell. It started taking near 12-15 Mins in running the app on simulator. The issue was resolved after I removed this lib from my code and added [VMSignatureView](https://github.com/VaibhavMisra/VMSignatureView) and my compilation time went into normal state.

Second time I faced this issue after making a code of appending several Strings. Both of these below methods turned app's compilation time to hell

```
a = a + b
```

and

```
a += b
```

Then I changed my code to below way and the problem was solved.

```
a = "a\(strSometihng),\(strAnother)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating several Strings also can cause increasing compiling times, for example in my case, my compilation times where very high because of this line:

```
let fecha = post.dia + " " + post.num_dia + " " + post.mes + " - " + post.hora
```

When i changed the code to this, it satart compiling in seconds:

```
var fecha = post.dia!
fecha = fecha + " "
fecha = fecha + post.num_dia!
fecha = fecha + " "
fecha = fecha + post.mes!
fecha = fecha + " - "
fecha = fecha + post.hora!
```