# XCode 8 Stuck on Running 2 of 4 Custom Shell Script

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, shell

Xcode is taking about 7 minutes to run my build my app on my phone. I am having this problem with 3 different apps all with Fabric and CocoPods installed. I have turned `Optimization` to none. The only common cocopod is Alimo fire. Below are my custom shell scripts:

[image]

[image]

It is becoming a huge pain to test anything on my device. I can run errands and be back home before it finishes building. I have on a mac pro so system resources are not the issue. Thanks!

**Edit 1**

It looks like the `[CP] Embed Pods Framewords` is taking the longest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It had over 1200 appleid certificates, so it was taking a while to sign the cocopods. To fix:

1. Open keychain
2. Click `Certificates`
3. Search `appleid`
4. Select all `CMD-A`
5. Press `delete`

Reference: [XCode 7.3.1 hangs on "copying swift standard libraries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084280/xcode-7-3-1-hangs-on-copying-swift-standard-libraries)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was gold and saved me hours :) !

Answer (score 1):

- To narrow down which step is slow, when building open the build via Report Navigator (Cmd-8).
- Have you tried restarting Xcode?
- Try excluding your build's DerivedData folder from Time Machine.
- Are you up to date on cocoapods?

Comment: I have tried restarting xcode and clearing derived data. It looks like `[CP] Embed Pods Framewords` it taking all of the time.

Comment: I am using cocopod v1.1.1, I have cleared my derived data and don't use time machine. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem.

To fix it check the box for "Run script only when installing" in Target - Build Phases - Run script