# react native ios build take long time

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, watchman

React native project I build in Xcode, always stuck on "Running 2 of 4 custom shell script" and take nearly 5 min to continue. After that the bundling process in react packager also take very long time.

eg : Bundling `index.ios.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  ▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  18.3% (412/962), almost one second to increase only one. But last time I was building react native android version in Windows and the bundling process is very fast.

I have searched for some solution like this one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729925/xcode-8-stuck-on-running-2-of-4-custom-shell-script) tried result are same, and someone said is watchman problem so I reinstall `watchman` using `brew`, the result is same also, performance did not increase.

*RN version:*

**react-native-cli: 2.0.1**

**react-native: 0.48.4**

Comment: Did you find any solution?